# Python Subsetting by Column Values

Tags: python

This should be a fairly simple task, but I can't find it anywhere. I have two data sets, and I would like to subset the first one to only include records in the second. Each Table has a common column of the account identifier.

I tried using:

```
ma2 = ma[ma.LID.isin(df.LID)]
```

Where:
`ma` is my main dataframe size=(133788, 8),
`df` is my second table size = (2367,4),
`LID` is my column name with the unique account identifier.

My goal is to get a dataframe ma = (2367, 8)

This resulted in ma2 being size = (0, 8). Not what I want(unless the values of the second table are not in the first, which I know they are)

I also tried:

```
ma2 = ma[(ma['LID'].isin(df['LID']))]
```

which resulted in the opposite ma2 size = (0,8)

Thanks for the help. If needed I can try to create a reproducible example, but I don't think it will be needed.

Here is a brief example of what I would be looking at and trying to accomplish:

Table ma:

```
LID colB colC colD
1   a     ab   x 
2   b     ab   y 
3   a     ac   y 
4   b     ac   x
```

Table df:

```
LID colC colE  
1    ab    w  
2    ab    w   
4    ac    w
```

New subset of ma:

```
LID colB colC colD  
1   a     ab   x  
2   b     ab   y  
4   b     ac   x
```

Hope the example helps clarify what I'm doing.

Comment: try putting a a few entities of `df` that you know are present in `ma`. Ex - if you know that `'ABC'` is in `df['LID']` try `ma[ma['LID'] == 'ABC']` do you see any rows ?

Comment: [minimal verifyable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) does think it would be better that _you_ spend the time to prepare your question as best as you can then that 100`s of _we_ have to create your code for you.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I can subset out single rows like that by calling a specific value, but am unable to figure out how to do it on multiple values as in a list, or whole column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this:

```
ma.loc[ ma.LID.isin( df.LID ) ]
```

Note the difference between your original expression (the added `.loc`).

The expression `ma.loc[ list-like-object ]` selects rows by a Boolean vector (which must be the same length as `ma`). The rows that have 'true' will be returned.

(on the other hand, in expressions like `df[ something ]`, the 'something' is usually a column or a list of columns, not what you intended).

NOTE that while `ma.loc[ ma.LID.isin( df.LID ) ]` should work, it isn't very efficient for large amounts of data. You might want to re-index your dataframe (or a copy of it) to have the values in LID as the index, then you can select them directly with `ma_indexed_by_LOC.loc[ df.LOC ]`. (this is assuming that the LOC values are unique).

Comment: note I assume that your data is in `pandas` DataFrame objects, if this is the case, please tag your question with `pandas`.